# matplotlib histogram rearrange x labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a histogram and it is not displaying the x labels as I wish.
Code for the histogram creation

```
respond_plt = z['Respond Duration Category'].hist()
respond_plt

plt.title('Number of Calls \nPer Respond Time (Days)')
plt.xlabel('Respond Time (Days)')
plt.ylabel('Number of Calls')
```

The x axis of the histogram currently goes

```
['<= 5 days', '15-22 days', '6-15 days']
```

Instead, I would like to rearrange them into:

```
['<= 5 days', '6-15 days', '15-22 days']
```

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using a histogram, while you want to create a count plot. Seaborn's [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) creates a bar for each unique value. The `order=` parameter can set a fixed order (default the labels would be sorted "alphabetically").

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

duration = ['<= 5 days', '6-15 days', '15-22 days']
z = pd.DataFrame({'Respond Duration Category': np.random.choice(duration, 100)})

# ax = z['Respond Duration Category'].hist()
ax = sns.countplot(z['Respond Duration Category'], order=duration, color='dodgerblue')
ax.set_title('Number of Calls \nPer Respond Time (Days)')
ax.set_xlabel('Respond Time (Days)')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Calls')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting example plot]